# calendar array previous next month

Tags: php, arrays, calendar

So I'm creating a calendar application to put in a website, It's supposed to:

- Show current month
- Show next (3) months
- Show 2 previous months
- show the end of previous and start of next month ( if layout lets you )(like windows calender also does.)

So right now i'm at the point where my code generates me a array with all data, it automaticly makes it start at the right position and (according to first day of the month) and it sets the default amount of days to 42. (as that's how windows has done it.)

This is the array output : https://pastebin.com/NqLzNW5Z
This is my Calendar.class.php file : https://pastebin.com/Hin8q7xW (some words are dutch, excuse me for this.)

My question: how do i change the following :

```
        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => Before Month Start
                [1] => Before Month Start
                [2] => Before Month Start
                [3] => 01-06-2017
                [4] => 02-06-2017
                [5] => 03-06-2017
                [6] => 04-06-2017
                [7] => 05-06-2017
                [8] => 06-06-2017
                [9] => 07-06-2017
                [10] => 08-06-2017
                [11] => 09-06-2017
                [12] => 10-06-2017
                [13] => 11-06-2017
                [14] => 12-06-2017
                [15] => 13-06-2017
                [16] => 14-06-2017
                [17] => 15-06-2017
                [18] => 16-06-2017
                [19] => 17-06-2017
                [20] => 18-06-2017
                [21] => 19-06-2017
                [22] => 20-06-2017
                [23] => 21-06-2017
                [24] => 22-06-2017
                [25] => 23-06-2017
                [26] => 24-06-2017
                [27] => 25-06-2017
                [28] => 26-06-2017
                [29] => 27-06-2017
                [30] => 28-06-2017
                [31] => 29-06-2017
                [32] => 30-06-2017
                [33] => After month
                [34] => After month
                [35] => After month
                [36] => After month
                [37] => After month
                [38] => After month
                [39] => After month
                [40] => After month
                [41] => After month
            )
```

To something like this :

```
        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => 29-05-2017
                [1] => 30-05-2017
                [2] => 31-05-2017
                [3] => 01-06-2017
                [4] => 02-06-2017
                [5] => 03-06-2017
                [6] => 04-06-2017
                [7] => 05-06-2017
                [8] => 06-06-2017
                [9] => 07-06-2017
                [10] => 08-06-2017
                [11] => 09-06-2017
                [12] => 10-06-2017
                [13] => 11-06-2017
                [14] => 12-06-2017
                [15] => 13-06-2017
                [16] => 14-06-2017
                [17] => 15-06-2017
                [18] => 16-06-2017
                [19] => 17-06-2017
                [20] => 18-06-2017
                [21] => 19-06-2017
                [22] => 20-06-2017
                [23] => 21-06-2017
                [24] => 22-06-2017
                [25] => 23-06-2017
                [26] => 24-06-2017
                [27] => 25-06-2017
                [28] => 26-06-2017
                [29] => 27-06-2017
                [30] => 28-06-2017
                [31] => 29-06-2017
                [32] => 30-06-2017
                [33] => 01-07-2017
                [34] => 02-07-2017
                [35] => 03-07-2017
                [36] => 04-07-2017
                [37] => 05-07-2017
                [38] => 06-07-2017
                [39] => 07-07-2017
                [40] => 08-07-2017
                [41] => 09-07-2017
            )
```

Note : The first and last month which is able to be seen doesn't have to show one month earlier and one month later. As this would require me to load in another month. just for those couple of days.

The end result will be put together with a slider. When the used clicks the next month arrow the slider wil display the next month.

If someone knows how to help me get this done, please do let me know. If someone knows a better approach to this, Also please do let me know!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, so let me know if you run into any problems.

```
    public function makeMonth($m, $y)
    {

        $maand = array();
        // Get info for this year
        $info = $this->getInfo($m, $y);

        // Get array with dates
        $amount = $info['days'];
        $dateStart = strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-1");
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++) {
            $maand[$i] = str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "-" . $m . "-" . $y;
            $dateEnd = strtotime("{$y}-{$m}-{$i}");
        }

        // place the array content correctly
        $needed = 42;
        $begin = $info['firstday'] - 1;
        $nognodig = $needed - ($begin + $amount);

        #begin van array
        while ($begin > 0) {
            $begin--;
            $dateStart = strtotime("-1 day", $dateStart);
            array_unshift($maand, date("d-m-Y", $dateStart));
        }

        #eind van array
        while ($nognodig > 0) {
            $nognodig--;
            $dateEnd = strtotime("+1 day", $dateEnd);
            array_push($maand, date("d-m-Y", $dateEnd));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I changed the "d-M-Y" to "d-m-Y" tho. So it displays the number. Thanks a lot! accepting your answer.

Comment: Updated solution.